# How to get the actual URL a post/submit form redirects to?

Tags: url, post, forms

As you may know when you submit data through a form you are actually accessing an URL with your submitted data included in the URL as the query strings.

*For example*, 
if the form asks you to submit your name, age and job when you press submit you are actually being redirected to the URL below:

`http:testsite.com/form.php?send=profile&name=john&age=23&job=engineer`

My question is how do I get this URL from any form? I used to had a Firefox extension that could do it but I forgot the name and I cant find it anymore.

Comment: The answer is: you view the HTML.  When there is a <FORM> tag, there is a corresponding <INPUT type="submit"> button that specifies the URL to submit to.  Note that it likely uses http://, not just http:

Comment: But how do I get the other parameters?

Comment: That's really a separate question, so it shouldn't be asked as part of this question.  However, before asking that question, make sure to do your own preliminary research, including using a search engine (like Google, which is an excellent choice) to look up details on this topic.  See if a walkthrough is easily findable, which may tell you about how HTML specifies the form parameters.

Comment: I already did that but I cant find anything because I dont know the keywords I should search. Also, its not a separate question because I am asking for a method to get the FULL URL which includes parameters, strings and everything just like in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the page source and browsing to the `<form>` tag will tell you where the data is supposed to go. All the fields (the parameters you mentioned) in that particular form will conventionally be sent to the page specified in `form action`.

For analyzing the submitted data, use an interception tool ([burpsuit](https://portswigger.net/burp/) is an excellent example). That way, you'll be able to figure out what is going where.

Comment: Dont you have a free solution? The Firefox extension was for free. If not, I would appreciate if you tell me what keywords I can use to search on google.

Comment: The free edition of burpsuit would be enough for satisfying your current requirements. It is not that difficult to use it, give it a try. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with any firefox extensions that does what burpsuit can do.

Comment: How is that process or whatever exactly called? Fetching a request URL from a form or something?

Comment: Hey! Anybody there??

Answer (score 0):

A free and full solution is wireshark, it is a bit complicated and will have to add filters as its not just web traffic.

(plugin for FF) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/HTTP_logging

google web sniffer or analyzer etc